# Jquery DataTable individual column search selected input not showig/working?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, datatables

I am using `jquery DataTable` and try to apply individual column search in header or footer of table but its not working.
https://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html
Same above like this but its not working.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
       
    var table =$('#customerDatatable').DataTable({
            "bDestroy": true,
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
          
            "iDisplayLength" : 100,
           
            buttons: [
                'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
            ],
                    "autoWidth": true,
            "responsive": true,
            "lengthChange": true,
            "ordering": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "https://localhost:7274/fwRules/LoadData/",
            "dataSrc": ""
        },
            
        "columns": [
            { "data": "srcip" },
            { "data": "srcport" },
            { "data": "dstip" },
            { "data": "dstport" },
           
            { "data": "date" },
                { "data": "count" }],
            initComplete: function () {
                this.api()
                    .columns()
                    .every(function () {
                        var column = this;
                        var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                            .appendTo($(column.footer()).empty())
                            .on('change', function () {
                                var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex($(this).val());

                                column.search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false).draw();
                            });

                        column
                            .data()
                            .unique()
                            .sort()
                            .each(function (d, j) {
                                select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>');
                            });
                    });
            },
          

        
    });
        
       
    
    });
```

output:
[image: output]
`DataTable` contains more then 50k records, data is showing but `column filter` not showing, i also check `console` in browser no error is showing please help.

Comment: You have provided a link to an [official example](https://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html). Your code is very different from that example. Why is that? Or, if you want input fields instead of select fields (drop-downs), use [this other official example](https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html). What you have right now is neither of these approaches. You have a comment in your code `// Setup - add a text input to each footer cell` - but the code which actually does this is missing.

Comment: Please take a closer look at those two official examples. Pick the one you want to use. Implement that approach. If you get stuck you can ask a new, much more specific question. But the examples should solve your problems.

Comment: i already apply code to official example but still its not showing any filter or columns

Comment: "_I already apply code..._"- No, you have not done that. Not according to the code you are showing us in your question.

Comment: ok let me update code

Comment: please check my updated code, also this code not showing any filter columns as well

Comment: You are still not implementing the code as shown in the official example. Please check again. For example (and like I mentioned already), you have a comment in your code `// Setup - add a text input to each footer cell` - but the code which actually does this is missing from your code. So there is one place where you have not followed the official example correctly. There are other differences, too.

Comment: Also, where is your HTML? As you can see in the official example, it needs to have a footer section - otherwise, there is nowhere to place the search select tools. Take another closer look at the example. If there is something you don't understand then don't just ignore it - instead, you can ask a _specific_ question about that _specific_ section of code.